# Limit max connections per IP address and new connections per second with NETSHADVFIREWALL OR WINDOWS FIREWALL ANY

Tags: windows

IPTABLES - Do you know a similar windows security wall?

NETSH ADVFIREWALL - How can I set the maximum number of connections for an ip address through?

How to use this commands with netsh advfirewall ??  - OR EX WINDOWS FIREWALL PROGRAM

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 15100 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 15 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 150/second --limit-burst 160 -j ACCEPT

Comment: please put this in context

Comment: that script is hacky and won't prevent DDOS in any way

Comment: I can't understand what do you say?
The question I ask is not clear enough?
I want to limit the maximum connection of the ip addresses in the Windows operating system and how can do that.

Script is not a problem, I found it on the internet. I do not even know how it works.

Comment: admins use network devices for this type of thing, firewall, or load balancer. there are specific DDOS prevention algorithms, you don't mention what you are protecting or what type of traffic

Comment: L3 / L4 / L7 - UDP - TCP - I put an obstacle on all attack types. There is no problem with these DDoS attack types.

For example, I need to set something like 15100 TCP port so that the same ip address can be connected up to per 30 seconds max 10 incoming session.

15100 TCP Port maximum - I need to make a setting like 10 times in 30 seconds.

Comment: I would look at off the shelf solutions such as NGINX and fail2ban

Comment: We need running windows platform firewall.

I Now everything Nginx ad others. Nginx and Fail2ban = garbage

Comment: you can't mitigate an actual attempted DDOS attack my turning windows firewall rules on, it's just not that simple

Comment: Yes, you need a DDoS protection system for windows.

It would have been nice if only a few rules could be configured.